# ConTeXt ignores value of leftmargin

Tags: margins, context

I am trying to customize the page setup in ConTeXt. Following [ConTeXt garden](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/setuplayout#Horizontal), I use the setting `width=fit`. Whereas adjusting the parameter `rightmargin` works just fine, changing `leftmargin` has no effect at all on the layout. See the below MWE, where I gave it an absurdly high value; nothing happens no matter what I set it to. Changing to `width=middle`, I can solve the problem using other parameters, but I would like to know how to solve the problem with `width=fit`.

**A side question:** When should I use the two settings of `width`?

```
\setuplayout[
    width=fit,
    rightmargin=4cm,
    leftmargin=15cm,
%   width=middle,
%   backspace=4cm,
%   cutspace=15cm,
]

\starttext

\input knuth

\input tufte

\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: The distance between the left margin and the text is controlled with the `backspace` key, the right margin and the text is set by the `cutspace` key. The width of the text block can be calculated in two ways, the first is to set a certain value with `width=<DIMENSION>` and the second is to use `width=middle` where the textblock is the result of the `paperwidth` minus the values set by the `backspace` and `cutspace` keys.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Layout (and my personnal experience), you should use

```
\setuplayout[
    width=fit,
    rightmargin=4cm,
    backspace=15cm,
%   width=middle,
%   backspace=4cm,
%   cutspace=15cm,
]

\starttext

\input knuth

\input tufte

\stoptext
```

I have never used the width=middle, but I personnaly like to give a precise width when not in a generic setting. e.g.

```
\definepapersize[MySlide][
    height=38.10cm,
    width=67.73cm]
\setuppapersize[MySlide][MySlide]
\setuplayout[
    backspace=9cm,
    leftmargin=9cm,
    rightmargin=9cm,
    topspace=25mm,
    header=25mm, 
    footerdistance=8mm,
    footer=10mm,
    height=344mm,
    width=49.73cm]
```